# Ссылки с префиксом mailto

Tags: email, html

```
<a href="mailto:info@hashcode.ru">Email</a>
```

Часто встречаю злосчастный mailto, который, после моего неосмотрительного нажатия, открывает MS Outlook. Неужели им ещё кто-то пользуется, и простите за безграммотность и непросвящённость, какие программы могут открываться по нажатию такой вот ссылки? Кроме MS Outlook?
А также какие ещё бывают префиксы помимо этого?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По нажатию на ссылки типа `mailto:` открывается установленная в системе по умолчанию программа для отправки почты. Если установить theBat, или, к примеру, веб-приложение GMail, то будет открываться эта программа.

Comment: Это понятно, спасибо, а вот популярность использования? Часто ли вы пользуйтесь этой конструкцией как программист и как рядовой пользователь?

Comment: Никогда :)

Answer (score 2):

[URI схемы](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A8%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD:URI_scheme)

Comment: Спасибо большое за список, давно искал нечто подобное.
Странно, что там нет "javascript:".

Answer (score 1):

В файерфоксе по нажатию на такую штуку открывается окошечко, что именно выбрать. В том числе gmail, нажимаешь его - открывается форма отправки письма с вставленным адресом. Открывается прямо по http. В ореге похожая штука, по умолчанию может открывать яндекс; всё это можно настраивать. Кроме того, в ореге небольшой почтовик есть.

Короче говоря есть ещё смысл в этой ссылке :)

Answer (score 1):

Вообще для отправки формы с сайта используют php и без всяких почтовых программ...
сделайте так:
 `<a href="contacts.html">Email</a>`.

Вот код страницы contacts.html:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post" action="mail.php">
<p><strong>Ваше имя:</strong><br />
<input type="text" name="name" size="30"/>
<br />
<strong>Имя компании:</strong><br />
<input type="text" name="company" size="30"/>
<br />
<strong>Ваш e-mail (для ответа):</strong><br/>
<input name="email" type="text" size="30" />
<br />
<strong>Ваш заказ:</strong><br />
<textarea name="mess" rows="6" cols="60"></textarea>
<p>
<input type="submit" value="Отправить сообщение"/>
</p>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

А вот mail.php, который вы должны разместить в той же папке, где contacts.html:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1251"/>
<title>Обратная связь</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
$reg_test = "/^[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9\-\._]*[a-z0-9])@[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9\-]*[a-z0-9])\.[a-z0-9]+$/i";
if (isset($_POST['name'])) {
    $name = $_POST['name'];
}
if (isset($_POST['company'])) {
    $company = $_POST['company'];
}
if (isset($_POST['email'])) {
    $email = $_POST['email'];
}
if (isset($_POST['mess'])) {
    $mess = $_POST['mess'];
}

if (empty($name)) {
    echo "<b>Не указано имя!<p>";
    echo "<a href=contacts.html>Вернуться к заполнению формы</a>";
    exit;
} else if (empty($company)) {
    echo "<b>Не указано имя компании!<p>";
    echo "<a href=contacts.html>Вернуться к заполнению формы</a>";
    exit;
} else if (empty($email)) {
    echo "<b>Не указан e-mail!<p>";
    echo "<a href=contacts.html>Вернуться к заполнению формы</a>";
    exit;
} else if (!preg_match($reg_test, $email)) {
    echo "<b>Не правильно указан e-mail!<p>";
    echo "<a href=contacts.html>Вернуться к заполнению формы</a>";
    exit;
}

else if (empty($mess)) {
    echo "<b>Сообщение не написано!<p>";
    echo "<a href=contacts.html>Вернуться к заполнению формы</a>";
    exit;
} else
    $to = "info@prodimprt.pro";

/*УКАЗАТЬ СВОЙ АДРЕС!*/
$headers = "Content-type: text/plain; charset = windows-1251";
$subject = "ON-LINE заказ с сайта PRODIMPORT.PRO";
$message = "Имя пославшего: $name \nИмя компании:$company \nЭлектронный адрес: $email \nСообщение: $mess";
$send    = mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
if ($send == 'true') {
    echo "<b>Спасибо за отправку вашего сообщения!<p>";
    echo "<a href=index.htm>Нажмите,</a> чтобы вернуться на главную страницу";
} else {
    echo "<p><b>Ошибка. Сообщение не отправлено!";
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Спасибо за подробный код. Стоит рассмотреть его поближе, никогда не сталкивался с подобными решениями со стороны разработчика, хотя обычным пользователем видел часто. Мне кажется за этой системой несомненный плюс! И контроль вводимых данных есть, а значит некая систематизация, и дизайн свой прикрутить не проблема. Шикарно, одним словом! : D

Comment: В этом коде несомненно все верно так что можете согласиться с ответом

Answer (score 1):

MS Outlook - отличная вещь для больших фирм, для домашнего использования не удобна. У нас на фирме вся почта идет через Outlook, все интегрировано в рабочую сеть.

"Вообще для отправки формы с сайта используют php и без всяких почтовых программ..."
Это для обратной связи. Подходит не всегда, т.к. за частую многим необходимо иметь копию того, что отправил.

Answer (score 0):

mailto в принципе иногда может быть полезен тем, кто пользуется почтовым клиентом.

Удобство в том, что mailto автоматизирует процесс написания темы сообщения, нескольких адресатов и т.д.